# Why isn't $\mathbb Z\big[\sqrt d\big]$ a quadratic integer ring when $d \equiv 1 \pmod 4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am trying to understand quadratic integer rings. The following is assuming $d$ is square-free.

From my understanding so far:

$\mathbb Z\big[\sqrt d\big]$ is an integral domain.

$\mathbb Q\big[\sqrt d\big]$ is a field.

$\mathbb Q\big[\sqrt d\big]$ is the field of fractions of $\mathbb Z\big[\sqrt d\big]$.

$\mathbb Z\big[\sqrt d\big]$ is the ring of quadratic integers when $d \equiv 2,3 \pmod 4$.

$\mathbb Z \left[\frac{1+\sqrt d}{2} \right]$ is the ring of quadratic integers when $d \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Why isn't $\mathbb Z\big[\sqrt d\big]$ a quadratic integer ring when $d \equiv 1 \pmod 4$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that there are multiple ways of writing the field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt d)$: for example
$$\mathbb Q(\sqrt d)=\mathbb Q(7\sqrt d)= \mathbb Q(1 + \sqrt d) = \mathbb Q\left(\frac{17\sqrt d}{73}\right)$$
As such, there is no reason that we should *expect* the ring of integers of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt d)$ to be $\mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$, in exactly the same way that the ring of integers of $\mathbb Q(7\sqrt d)$ shouldn't be $\mathbb Z[7\sqrt d]$, even though the latter is an integral domain, and has field of fractions $
\mathbb Q(\sqrt d)$.

Since $\sqrt d$ is an algebraic integer, we can be sure that the ring of integers contains $\mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$, but this does not prevent the ring of integers from containing other elements. The idea is to find an *integral basis* for the ring of integers, and this will depend on the choice of $d$.

In the case that $d\equiv 1\pmod 4$, as Crostul points out, $\mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$ is not integrally closed, since $\frac{1+\sqrt d}2$ is a root of $X^2 -X +\frac{1-d}4$.

Comment: Why isn't $\mathbb Z \left[\frac{1+\sqrt d}{2} \right] = \mathbb Z\big[\sqrt d\big]$? Is it because $1/2$ is not in $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: That's correct. Specifically, $\frac{1+\sqrt d}2$ cannot be written in the form $a+b\sqrt d$ for $a,b\in \mathbb Z$, and all elements of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$ are of that form.

Answer (score 1):

Because in this case $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ is not integrally closed, since $\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}$ is a root of $x^2-x+\frac{1-d}{4}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf Z[\sqrt d]$ is indeed a ring of quadratic integers, but it's not **the** ring of quadratic integers of $\mathbf Q(\sqrt d)$. What you should understand is that $\mathbf Z[\sqrt d]\subset\mathbf Z\Bigl[\dfrac{1+\sqrt d}2\Bigr]$, which the full ring of quadratic integers if $d\equiv 1\mod 4$.

This is closely linked to the problem of when an integer can be written as the sum of two squares

Comment: Can you give an example of an element from $\mathbb Z \left[\frac{1+\sqrt d}{2} \right]$ that is not in $\mathbb Z\big[\sqrt d\big]$.

Comment: Well, one is well known since high school (though in another context): $\,j=\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}2$ has norm $1$, but it is not of the form $x+y\sqrt{-3}$ ($x,y\in\mathbf Z$), since the latter can have norm $x^2+3y^2=1$  only if $x=\pm 1, y=0$.